# Desktop enviroment dissapeared (20.04)

Tags: login, kde, desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome

Hi guys I'm in desperate need for help.

I was using my computer in the morning like normal, shut it down and turned it on like 6 hours later but after booting, it will stay in black screen forever, no errors, simply a black screen, my disk is encrypted so before that I have to type a password, but when is time to log in the black screen appears and stays there forever.

I think I might have an idea of what caused this but not sure if its really that or something else. In the morning I installed `kde-full`, tried it, didn't like it, so I removed it, but used the command `sudo apt purge kde-full --autoremove` and maybe `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove sddm` too, loged out of the session, changed my DE to default gnome and continued working like normal, no errors, I simply kept working like normal.

So now I'm trying to use my computer but after unlocking the disk instead of the login screen I get a black screen, what I did was restart the machine many times, entered in the `Advanced options for ubuntu` mode and was able to use only the terminal, but could login and browse my files, but not gui, just terminal, any way to fix and get back my ubuntu to normal?

here some pics of some screens with errors not sure if they will help. (sorry for the quality)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help appreciated, this is my school machine and I have classes tomorrow, so even a temporary solution will do as long as I can use it for my classes.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you try `systemctl start gdm3`? or `startx`?

Comment: also how did you change your dm to gnome?

Comment: will try with the systemctl start, I logged out of the session and was sent back to the  login screen, there I had a button that allowed me pick the DE

Comment: @Esther I can run ```systemctl start gdm3``` and works!
thanks! but when I reboot the machine the same problem persists

Comment: try `apt install --reinstall gdm3`. This might replace some config files or other lines that are missing from the system.

Comment: thanks you for your help, it works!